# Spacy project yml environment variable

Tags: spacy

I have a Spacy project with the following command section:

```
commands:
- name: "get-models"
  help: "Downloads trained models from s3."
  script:
    - "python scripts/get_models.py"
  deps:
    - "scripts/get_models.py"
```

My `get_models.py` script requires environment variables `S3_ACCESS_KEY` and `S3_SECRET_KEY` and consumes them via `os.getenv('S3_ACCESS_KEY')` and `os.getenv('S3_SECRET_KEY')` respectively.

How can I pass environment variables to my `scripts/get_models.py` script when running `python -m spacy project run get-models`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `.env` file in your folder with the environment variables, you can add `dotenv run --` to your script. So your new command would look like:

```
commands:
- name: "get-models"
  help: "Downloads trained models from s3."
  script:
    - "dotenv run -- python scripts/get_models.py"
  deps:
    - "scripts/get_models.py"
```